# 2D Plot for PDE

Tags: plotting

I made scheme for diffusion equation
And I know how to make `Plot3D`
But how to make `Plot2D` with different time?

```
tt = 0.1;

tnn = 100;

xnn = 20;

tau = tt/tnn;

h = 1/xnn;

u0[x_] := 1;

Do[v[i, 0] = u0[h*i], {i, 0, xnn/2}]
Do[v[i, 0] = 0, {i, xnn/2 + 1, xnn}]

Do[v[0, n] = 0; v[xnn, n] = 0;
 Do[v[i, n + 1] = 
   v[i, n] + tau/h^2*(v[i - 1, n] - 2*v[i, n] + v[i + 1, n]), {i, 1, 
   xnn - 1}], {n, 0, tnn - 1}]

u = ListInterpolation[
   Table[v[i, j], {i, 0, xnn}, {j, 0, tnn}], {{0, 1}, {0, tt}}];

Plot3D[u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tt}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Why not use `NDSolve[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Key idea is to create list of "lines" for each time. For this I use the `Table`. `Evaluate` makes sure, that things get evaluated in the correct order.

```
timeList = Range[0, 0.1, 0.025]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[u[x, t], {t, timeList}], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> timeList]
```

[image]

In addition I would use `InterpolationOrder->1` in order to avoid nonphysical artifacts.

```
u = ListInterpolation[
   Table[v[i, j], {i, 0, xnn}, {j, 0, tnn}], {{0, 1}, {0, tt}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

ListPlot3D[Table[{i, j, v[i, j]}, {i, 0, xnn}, {j, 0, tnn}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
timeList = Range[0, 0.1, 0.025]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[u[x, t], {t, timeList}], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> timeList]
```

[image]